# comparison operator values C++

Tags: c++, c, boolean, operator-keyword

We all know C++ (while not a superset) is pretty much derived from C.

In C++, the operators  <, <=, >, >=, ==, and != all have boolean return values.
However, in C, the same operators returned 1 or 0, since there was no 'bool' type in C.

Since all integer values except 0 are treated as "true", and 0 is "false", I want to know:

Does C++ still restrict the return values of the operators to be 1 vs 0, or does a 'true', from one of these operators, return any 1-byte value, so long as it isn't 0?

I want to know since using these return values as explicit 1 or 0 would be useful in bitwise operations without branching.

As a terrible example, take the following:

```
bool timesTwo;
int value;

//...

if(timesTwo)
    value << 1;

//vs

value << (int) timesTwo;
```

Comment: I dont understand what youre asking, C++ operators return a boolean, not an int.

Comment: your example is fine, the `int` cast will transform `true` into 1, or `false` into 0.

Comment: Is your question equivalent to the question of whether `int a(5); assert( (int)((bool)a) == 1 );` will always be ok?

Comment: @MattPhillips Somewhat.  Let us ASSUME for a second that casting an int, to a bool, back to an int, retains its original value, such that `assert( (int)((bool)(5)) == 5 )`.  Under THAT assumption, my question was actually asking something more along the lines of whether `int x; assert( ((int)( x == x )) == 1);` would hold, which gives question to the actual byte returned by the `x == x` comparison.  However, since casting to an int is always 0 or 1, the question becomes (almost) meaningless.

Comment: Or, you could say that the question is asking if the following holds:
`bool b = (5 == 5); char* cp = (char*) (&b); assert( (*c) == ((char) 1) );`

Comment: @Serge: Only vaguely related to your question, you can overload those operators to return anything at all.  `struct A { std::string operator<(char) const {return "HI";}};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > Does C++ still restrict the return values of the operators to be 1 vs 0, or does a 'true', from one of these operators, return any 1-byte value, so long as it isn't 0?

The comparison operators, assuming that they have not been overloaded, only ever return `true` and `false`.

`int(true)` is always 1.

`int(false)` is always 0.

So,

```
int one(1), two(2);
assert( (one<two) == 1 );
assert( (two<one) == 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  While my question was more referring to the actual byte value that boolean holds (since it's never just 1 bit), I believe this provides the necessary clarification.

Comment: The standard is silent on that point. You can't know what byte value the boolean holds, but you *can* convert it to an int and inspect that.

Comment: Copied from one of my comments above, you could say that the question is asking if the following holds: `bool b = (5 == 5); char* cp = (char*) (&b); assert( (*c) == ((char) 1) );`

Comment: Practially, yes, that holds for every copmiler you are going to use. But, I'm not so sure it holds true in the standard. The standard language is all about conversions to/from integer types, and not about at all about representation.

Comment: Ok, thanks Rob!  Appreciate it!  While you originally gave me an answer to my main issue, out of curiosity I still wanted to know if something like that was defined;  Thanks for all the answers =)

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `bool` is automatically converted into integer in C++ (1 if true, 0 if false) when used in expressions and there's no need to cast.

```
value << (int) timesTwo;
```

The case is not necessary:
if `timesTwo`` is true then

you can directly do without a casr:

```
value<<timesTwo;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
value<<1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The type `bool` has two values: `false` and `true`. You can treat it as an integer, in which case, `false` is converted to 0 and `true` is converted to 1. That's all there is to it.

The C-style sort-of-boolean, where 0 is treated as false and non-zero is treated a true, leads to problems when someone naively does something like `#define FALSE 0` and `#define TRUE !FALSE`. That effectively defines `TRUE` as 1, and comparisons like `if (f() == TRUE)` can mysteriously fail. The correct test would be `if (f() != FALSE)`. Of course, with a real boolean type, that's not an issue, because values that aren't false will always be the same.